# Viewmodel has a list of items and each item has another list of items

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a datagrid with the following itemsource

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyItems, Mode=OneWay}"
```

Inside each item there is a collection called "MySubItems" and I want to show them in a combobox.. But somehow I can't reach them...

```
ItemsSource="{Binding MySubItems,Source={StaticResource MyItemsModel}}"
```

How do I implement this? thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use dot notation to access sub properties:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyItems.MySubItems, Mode=OneWay}"
```

Since you're trying to access properties on a sub object, however, I think the easiest way is to bind the grid to a selected value property and then have the combo box bound to that:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.SubItems}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedComboItem}"
          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"/>
```

DataGrid binding:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyItems, Mode=OneWay}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

Comment: hey don't remove your edit. that was my next question... how to keep track of the selected item on the same level. But thanks for your answer, I will accept it !

Comment: Sorry I wasn't correct in my original edit so I wanted to re-type it @user1841243